# How to dump Hibernate cascade tree

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Does anybody of you know if there is a tool to visualize the cascade delete tree?

My problem is that we seem to have run into a mess of Hibernate and JPA annotations in our project. The database design is valid, I can delete the desired entry via SQL by walking the database relations backwards according to the foreign keys and "DELETE from ...". Hibernate, though, runs into an error when executing the delete. What I can see in the log is, that it misses to execute a delete of an entity in the middle of the logical object tree to delete.

If there was a tool that displays the cascade tree Hibernate must build somehow in the back this would help to figure out where the annotation are wrong.

Comment: This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/) may help you to show SQL in your Console

Comment: Hi Abdou, thanks for the link! However, we already looked at the SQL in the debug log. What we saw is that Hibernate is just not executing the delete of the entity at the place one would do it when deleting manually. It's actually a colleague of mine working on that, therefore it's not so easy to put the current state of the code here. I just wondered if there is a way to dump the cascade tree while playing around with the annotations.

Comment: Did you use  @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE}) ??

Comment: We fixed the actual problem meanwhile. It was connected to a reference the was configured the "wrong direction" between the entities somehow. My question here was rather about the mentioned tool, but thank you for your support!